# how to translate angular page into respective language on language selection using google cloud translation

Tags: angular, google-cloud-translate

I am developing a basic website using Angular. I have a requirement to translate the complete page without using resource file approach. The end customer does not want to maintain the resource files in multiple languages and expect translation to happen on the fly using some translation service.

I have tried **using google cloud translation service**, but it takes only text as input. Please suggest if there is any better approach to achieve this requirement?

Comment: I don't think there's some thing that can do that on the fly and it would probably take a significant amount of load time if there was one. This is what I've used in the past for my previous project for multilingual project: https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/recipes/google-translate-integration

Comment: Why doesn't the end customer want to maintain the resource files? Sine as @penleychan if it's made on the fly it would take more time.